# Uniform initialization behavior different for different types in vector

Tags: c++11, vector

I came across [this](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) article in which I read this example by one of the posters. I have quoted that here for convenience.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int i) {} // #1
    Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> f {10};

    std::cout << f.size() << std::endl;
}
```

> The above code, as written, emits “1” (10 is a converted to Foo by a
>   constructor that takes an int, then the vector’s initializer_list
>   constructor is called). If I comment out the line commented as #1, the
>   result is “10” (the initializer_list cannot be converted so the int
>   constructor is used).

My question is why does it emit a 10 if the int constructor is removed.
I understand that uniform initialization list works in the following order

```
1-Calls the initializer list if available or possible
2-Calls the default constructor if available
3-Does aggregate initialization
```

In the above case why is it creating 10 items in the vector since 1,2 and 3 are not possible ? Does this mean with uniform initialization a vector of items might always have different behaviors ?

Comment: Your terminology seems to be off. The default c'tor is the one that can be invoked w/o arguments (if there are several such c'tors, due to default arguments, then an attempt to use it will be ambiguous). It can't be called here because that would require empty or no parens/braces. Aggregate initialization is only for PODs with no constructor, and does not apply to std::vector (it's used e.g. for std::array, and for other C-style structs). If you change 2. to "calls a constructor with compatible argument types", it would make more sense, but aggregate init. and c'tors are really either-or.

Comment: To clarify (I ran out of chars): aggregate initialization isn't ever a fallback from invoking some constructor. It is only available if the class or struct has no constructor at all. So if a class has a constructor, but neither a constructor taking std::initializer_list, nor a constructor with compatible arguments can be called, there is no fallback to aggregate initialization. Instead, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @ArneVogel Answers belong as answers - don't write multiparagraph comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing a quote from Scott Meyers in Effective Modern C++ (emphasis in original):

> If, however, one or more constructors declare a parameter of type `std::initializer_list`, calls using the braced initialization syntax strongly prefer the overloads taking `std;:initializer_list`s. *Strongly*. If there's *any way* for compilers to construe a call using a braced initializer to be a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`, compilers will employ that interpretation.

So when you have `std::vector<Foo> f {10};`, it will try to use the constructor of `vector<Foo>` that takes an `initializer_list<Foo>`. If `Foo` is constructible from an `int`, that is the constructor we're using - so we end up with one `Foo` constructed from `10`.

Or, from the standardese, in [over.match.list]:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor
>   in two phases:
>
> (1.1) — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the
>   argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>   (1.2) — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
>   candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements
>   of the initializer list.

If there *is* a viable initializer-list constructor, it is used. If you didn't have the `Foo(int )` constructor, there would not be a viable initializer-list constructor, and overload resolution the second time around would find the constructor of `vector` that takes a size - and so you'd get a vector of 10 default-constructed `Foo`s instead.